# Codeigniter image manipulating problems

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, gd

I'm trying to create a thumbnail of an image, for example, this one:
[image: original image]

I need the thumbnail to be 500x300. I've chosen a very wide image (944x168) for illustration.

The first thing I do in codeigniter is to scale up (or down) the image so that it is as small as possible but covers a 500x300 area. So in this case, I need to scale to 1685x300 since it is wider than it is high. I do this in codeigniter with the following setup:

```
$config=array(
   "image_library"=>"gd2",
   "source_image"=>"blah.png",
   "maintain_ratio"=>true,
   "master_dim"=>"height",  /* in this case, with a wide image, this is what I want*/
   "height"=>300,
   "width"=>1685   /* calculated by (width/height)*300 */
);
```

Then I perform it as follows:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

But codeigniter gives me this:
[image: wrong resize]
which is not what I expect because I have only resized at this stage, not cropped. It is the right resolution though, 1685x300

I expect this, but with a resolution of 1685x300
[image: corr]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: CI is cutting off images while resizing?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you get rid of `"master_dim"=>"height",`? You don't need that anyway as you have already calculated the correct dimensions.

Comment: just out of curiosity, make the resolution 1888X336 i.e. exact twice and then resize. see if it cuts off then. just a wild guess....

Comment: @jeroen, You're right, I don't need it. It's just a residue from hacking away at this problem.
It doesn't make a difference

Comment: @itachi, does the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was calling `$this->image_lib->resize()` twice.
Thanks for the help